# Fill Json with a list

Tags: c#, json, list

I want to generate a Json:

```
"MaterialDetails":  
[{  
      "SKU":"",  
      "Name":"",  
      "Quantity":"",  
      "Price":"",  
      "Amount":""  
}]
```

I have a list with 5 different "MaterialDetails".

I intend to go through my list and generate more than one "MaterialDetail" automatically for each "MaterialDetail" in my list. How can I do this? Thank you...

Comment: What programming language are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.  Can you add more details to your question?  For example, what does the source list look like?  Also, what is the process for generating "more than one MaterialDetail automatically for each MaterialDetail"?  Can you provide an example or two of what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the [newtonsoft json dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) through NuGet.

Then do something like:

```
string jsonList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourlist);
```